# Bash error using the column command: 'column: line too long'

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal

When I type this column command with my input file I get the following error

```
column -t text.txt > output
column: line too long
column: line too long
column: line too long
column: line too long
column: line too long
column: line too long
```

When I look at the file output it seems that the first half of the file(from left to right) is not printed.

Is there a way around this error? Is there a way to do exactly what the command would do otherwise without this error?

---

Sample input (Real input ~640 columns)

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
03  2   45  3
5   6   7   8
```

Sample output (Real output ~640 columns)

```
column1    column2  column3  column4
03         2        45       3
5          6        7        8
```

Comment: Well -- I reproduced the error!  That's a start!

Comment: OK -- you're going to LOVE this.  I pulled the source from the Fedora git repo.  (I'm running Fedora 25 now, and it fails there.)  Built `column` from the source.  And it **works**.  I didn't just do 640 columns, I did **6400** columns.  Still works.

Comment: I'm also getting this error on Mac OS 10.11.6

Comment: From `man column`: "BUGS Input lines are limited to LINE_MAX (2048) bytes in length." Setting LINE_MAX environment variable did not work, it is probably a fixed constant in the code.

Comment: for people like me who saw "line too long" even on VERY SHORT lines: you will also see this error if the final line of a file is not terminated with any newline character. (or, more generally, if the final bytes of STDIN you pipe to `column` does not end with a newline)

Comment: On Mac OS and the tip of lacking a newline at the end was what did the trick for me!

Comment: Yes, I just discovered this before reading these comments (I should have read further).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try a naive awk implementation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        max[i] = length($i) > max[i] ? length($i) : max[i]; next} 
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%-"max[i]"s  ", $i; printf "\n"}' text.txt text.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to split the line into an array.
This line is too long and `column` will not print it in full:

```
FULLTEXT=$(cat /Users/burroughclarke/Desktop/commaseperatedvalues.csv)
printf "$FULLTEXT" | column  -t -s ','
```

This prints it properly:

```
readarray -t ARR < <(cat /Users/burroughclarke/Desktop/commaseperatedvalues.csv | tr "\n" "\n") 
printf '%s\n' "${ARR[@]}" | column  -t -s ','
```

Answer (score 2):

Posting this comment from [@pestophagous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10278/pestophagous) because it is a legitimate answer and it answered the question *for me*:

> for people like me who saw "line too long" even on VERY SHORT lines: you will also see this error if the final line of a file is not terminated with any newline character. (or, more generally, if the final bytes of STDIN you pipe to column does not end with a newline)

I solved this in my own case by prepending a small `sed` command:

```bash
< input.txt sed 's/$/\n/' | column ...
```