# Visually align TSV using tabs

Tags: csv, awk, command-line-interface

I have a text file with fields, separated by some number of consequent tabs (so that the fields are all visually aligned). I'd like to add a lot of new fields to it from another (not aligned, pure tsv) file, while keeping everything aligned. A lot of values contain spaces in them, so only tabs (with assumed width of 8) can be used for alignment, because I want to be able to parse the file later by splitting each line on any number of consequent tabs. This means that I can't use tools like `column` or `tsv-pretty` as they use spaces for alignment. Is there a tool or a short script I can use to achieve what I want?

Example:

File 1:

```
AA      BB      CCC
AAAA    BBB     CCC
AA      BBBB    CC
```

File 2:

```
DD  EE  FF
DDDD    EE  FFFF
DD  EEEE    FF
```

Result:

```
AA      BB      CCC
AAAA    BBB     CCC
AA      BBBB    CC
DD      EE      FF
DDDD    EE      FFFF
DD      EEEE    FF
```

Comment: `awk` is a good starting point. What did you try with `awk` and why didn't it work as expected?

Comment: Well, I'm not even sure where to start with AWK to do that. It's easy to parse the file using awk, but I have no idea how to join the fields with tabs to that they're aligned.

Comment: @Discussian have a look at the accepted answer for [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338483/bash-error-using-the-column-command-column-line-too-long].  It may be a starting point for an `awk` solution.

Comment: @Discussian You could first try to analyze only your first file (and even the first record of it) and extract the starting column number of each field, assuming a tab width of 8. The `FPAT` GNU `awk` variable could be helpful, as it allows to define not what separates the fields, but what the fields are. In your case the fields could be defined as a non-empty sequence of not-tab characters, followed by one or more tabs, or the end of the record. `FPAT="[^\t]+(\t+|$)"`.

Comment: @Discussian Once you would have stored these starting column numbers in an array, you could process the second file with default fields definition and for each record and each field, print the field followed by a number of tabs that depends on the field width. All this should not be too difficult. And if there are specific parts of it on which you encounter issues, you already know where to ask **specific questions** about your coding issues.

Comment: @Discussian Maybe simpler: just parse your two files with awk, store in an array the maximum of each field width, parse them again and, this time, print them with the appropriate number of tabs between fields.

Comment: @Discussian One last hint: first use `sed` to substitute all spaces with a character that cannot be found in your files (e.g. `\034`). Then use `column` with tab as input field separator on your two files to align them with spaces. Finally use once more time `sed` to replace all strings of 8 consecutive spaces by a tab, all remaining strings of spaces by one tab, and the character you used in step 1 by space.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking about doing right now (store maximum, print with appropriate number of tabs). Although it'll be easier to do in perl or python than AWK. I just thought that maybe there's a already written tool that does what I want :)

Comment: The things that make your problem non-trivial are a) differing numbers of tabs required between fields to create visual alignment, and b) some fields containing blanks. But the example you provided has every field less than 8 chars and so is visually aligned with the same number of tabs (1) between all fields, and has no blanks within fields. So it's a bad example for both demonstrating your needs and for us to copy/paste to test with as a solution that doesn't do what you want would produce the output you posted from the input you posted. [edit] your question to provide a better example.

Comment: For example, `awk -v OFS='\t' '1' file{1,2}` would produce the output you posted from  the input you posted but that wouldn't address your requirements at all. Just changing the first field on the first line from `AA` to `AA AAA A` or any other string that's 8 or more chars long containing blanks so there's then 1 tab after the first field on the first line and 2 tabs after the first field on every other line would vastly improve your example. By the way, looking at previous comments - you don't need sed when you're using awk and it won't be easier to do this in perl or python than in awk.

Comment: The new file may have fields wide enough to break the existing alignment so you can't just count what tabs there are but have to do it all over,  So read all data into a data structure (array of arrays) and then go column by column: find the widest field and then go through others, figure out within how many tabs their width fits and add tabs accordingly. (If the widest field, which needs one tab, is 18 chars wide then a field which is 6 chars wide takes three tabs.  Etc.)  There's probably refinements I missed. A nice programming exercise. I can't commit my time to write this for you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question in hope that there's an existing tool or a simple awk/perl one-liner that can do what I want. Looks like there isn't, so I wrote a simple tool in Go that worked for my input. It doesn't handle a lot of things that a good tsv parser should (like escaping) but maybe it'll still be useful for someone else:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const tabWidth = 8

func tsvAlign(filenames []string) (err error) {
    var lines [][]string
    for _, filename := range filenames {
        file, err := os.Open(filename)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()

        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            lines = append(lines, strings.FieldsFunc(scanner.Text(), func(c rune) bool { return c == '\t' }))
        }
    }

    maxFieldWidths := make([]int, len(lines[0])-1, len(lines[0])-1)
    for i := 0; i < len(lines[0])-1; i++ {
        for _, line := range lines {
            if len(line[i]) > maxFieldWidths[i] {
                maxFieldWidths[i] = len(line[i])
            }
        }
    }

    for _, line := range lines {
        for i, field := range line[:len(line)-1] {
            padding := int(math.Ceil(float64(maxFieldWidths[i]+tabWidth-maxFieldWidths[i]%tabWidth)/8 - float64(len(field))/8))
            fmt.Print(field, strings.Repeat("\t", padding))
        }
        fmt.Println(line[len(line)-1])
    }

    return err
}

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "ERROR: No arguments provided")
        return
    }
    err := tsvAlign(os.Args[1:])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "ERROR: ", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Visual alignment is for human consumption don't save the file in that format, rather when you need to view the file use `column` to format it for you.

First need to get rid of the extra tabs in your first file and combine the files

```
$ cat <(tr -s '\t' <file1) file2 > file12
```

which will have the aligned columns by the delimiter (tab).  Now you can use `column -ts$'\t' file12` whenever you want to view the file which will align the columns for you.

This assumes you don't have missing fields.

Comment: Agreed. Not sure all the contortions to have the machine-readable version and the human-readable version be the _same_ file are worth it. Note that `column -ts $'\t'` presupposes you're using Bash. That feature, which the manual calls [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html), might not be present in other shells.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641242/785213), in that you'll make things easier on yourself if you use *single* tab characters as the delimiter in your data file, and let some other specialized tool (like `column -t`*) do the visual alignment for you, after the fact. This is a *great* use case for a Makefile or a Git pre-commit hook.

Since you've tagged this question `awk`, I still kinda feel it deserves an AWK-based answer, meeting your original requirements. But all the code necessary to accommodate the unusual input file format—as compared to karakfa's one-liner to just *reformat* the input file into something easier to work with—should tell you something. `;)`

For future reference, know that `-F` or `FS` in AWK is actually a regular expression, so your delimiter doesn't have to be a single character. I didn't notice this for *years* until I really started scrutinizing the manual. Its default is something like `[ \t]+`—that is, one or more consecutive whitespace characters.

Assuming your raw inputs look something like this

```bash
echo -e "AA\t\tBBBBBBBB\tCCC
AAAAAAAA\tBBB\t\tCCC
AA\t\tBBBB\t\tCC
AA AA AA AA AA\tBBBB BBBB\tCC" > file1

echo -e "DD\tEE\tFF
DDDD\tEE\tFFFF
DD\tEEEE\tFF" > file2
```

…this *almost* works

```bash
cat > format.awk <<EOF
BEGIN {
    TABWIDTH = TABWIDTH ? TABWIDTH : 8
    FS = "\t+"
    OFS = "\t"
}
function ceil(x) {
    return (x == int(x)) ? x : int(x) + 1
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        # store off values for later
        data[NR,i] = \$i
        if (length(\$i) > maxw[i])
            maxw[i] = length(\$i)
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<NF; j++) {
            printf data[i,j]
            # at least 1, plus 1 for every multiple of TABWIDTH less than max
            needtabs = ceil((maxw[j] - length(data[i,j])) / TABWIDTH) + 1
            for (k=1; k<=needtabs; k++)
                printf OFS
        }
        printf "%s\n", data[i,NF]
    }
}
EOF

awk -v TABWIDTH=8 -f format.awk file1 file2
```

Still working out a couple of kinks, and I'll update the answer accordingly.

Note that all the `$`s are escaped above, so the example will run when copy-pasted. If you *just* copy-paste the AWK code into your own script, fix those manually.

---

*A footnote about `column`: it does seem to have a [line length limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338483/bash-error-using-the-column-command-column-line-too-long), which you should be aware of if you're working with monstrous data files. I have a feeling that's not the case here. If it *were* the case, look into `mlr --tsv --opprint`<sup>[1](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)</sup> or `xsv table -d`<sup>[2](https://github.com/BurntSushi/xsv)</sup> as an alternative for your human-readable representation.

Comment: As an aside, I think the OP also nailed the reason that tabs-vs-spaces for indenting source files is such a contentious issue: tabs can have different widths, depending on terminal or editor settings, so using them for visual alignment _only_ works if everyone can agree on how wide a tab is in screen columns. Hence [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) and similar efforts.